# How to write event handler for buttons in adb shell?

Tags: android, linux, bash

Having the file for the character device is it possible to write simple shell script to process different button events? For example, if volume down was pressed - echo word "Low", and if volume up button press - echo "High".

Now I can keep track button press events using following command:

```
$ cat /dev/input/event2
  ≈►   ☺ s ☺   ≈►  →╟♂ ☺ s     ·►  r±☻ ☺ r ☺   ·►  a»      ☺ r
```

Current output contains information about 4 events:

- volume down (key press down event);
- volume down (key press up event);
- volume up (key press down event);
- volume up (key press up event).

Each event consists of 16 bytes of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
getevent -l
```

and get events as plain text, like

```
/dev/input/event1: EV_KEY       KEY_VOLUMEUP         UP                  
/dev/input/event1: EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000
```

Comment: Diego Torres Milano, thank you for useful hint. It should be mentioned that "getevent" utility may be used in a conjunction with the "-c" option (-c: print given number of events then exit).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Diego Torres Milano's hint, now I can write final solution for my FM radio button control shell script:

```
#!/system/bin/sh

while true
do
    event=$(getevent -c 2)

    if busybox printf -- '%s' "$event" | busybox egrep -q -- "0073 00000001"
    then
        busybox printf "Volume UP\n"
        input keyevent 25
        am broadcast -a com.android.fm.player.tune.next
    fi

    if busybox printf -- '%s' "$event" | busybox egrep -q -- "0072 00000001"
    then
        busybox printf "Volume DOWN\n"
        input keyevent 24
        am broadcast -a com.android.fm.player.tune.prev
    fi
done
```